# Url rewriting with user id

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to transform this url :

```
http://example.com/users_images/image.jpg
```

into :

`http://example.com/users_images/user_123/image.jpg` (123 is user id stored in session)

Is this possible to do this with url rewriting ?
If not, how are you dealing with this kind of problem ?
I don't want my users to access another users's documents.

Thanks

Comment: Where are the images stored? "users_images" or "users_images/[username]"?

Comment: users_images/[username]. I want them to all use the same link to access their images. So they can't guess others directories

Comment: easy way , use rewriting to map image.jpg to a php file like getimg.php and then use session to read image and sent it to browser

Comment: You will need to protect the directories anyway. URL rewriting doesn't protect you from users guessing other directories.
You could use http://example.com/getUserImage.php?image=image.jpg and return the image via PHP.

Comment: @PouyaDarabi Sorry, I wrote basically the same, but you were faster.

Comment: This is the way I was starting to do but I wasnt sure about replacing every images link with a PHP script. Also I'm not sure about managing the images mime type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to read out values from the php $_SESSION array in .htaccess for url rewriting. What you can do is to read out `%{HTTP_COOKIE}`, so you can store it there but i would avoid this practive.

I would make a a folder where you store the images and put there a .htaccess file with the following content to prevent every user to access it:

```
Deny from all
```

Then I would make a php script that is responsible for reading out the session vars and with the php function `fpassthrough()` you can pass the picture to the user. The php script can be called, when image is requestet for example:

```
RewriteRule users_images/(.*) /getpicture.php?image=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Ok, since 3 people tell me to do this way I will do it like this.
I accept this because of code example and upvote comments that were good too. Thanks